# Get data from Json file C#

Tags: c#, .net, json, visual-studio, file

I have this Json file:

```
{"id":88319,"dt":1345284000,"name":"Benghazi",
"coord":{"lat":32.12,"lon":20.07},
"main":{"temp":306.15,"pressure":1013,"humidity":44,"temp_min":306,"temp_max":306},
"wind":{"speed":1,"deg":-7},
"weather":[
             {"id":520,"main":"rain","description":"light intensity shower rain","icon":"09d"},
             {"id":500,"main":"rain","description":"light rain","icon":"10d"},
             {"id":701,"main":"mist","description":"mist","icon":"50d"}
          ],
"clouds":{"all":90},
"rain":{"3h":3}}
```

I can read the "name": "Benghazi" normally but the "temp":306.15 I can not read because it is inside "main":{}

I'm using a simple way to read, here is my C# code:

```
public class SkyWeather
{
    string path = @"http://api.openweathermap.org/data/2.5/weather?q=Uberaba,br&units=metric";

    string name;
    string temp;

    public string Name { get { return name; } set { name = value; } }
    public string Temp { get { return temp; } set { temp = value; } }

    public string GetTemperature()
    {
        var json = "";

        try
        {
            json = new WebClient().DownloadString(path);
        }
        catch (Exception e)
        {
            return e.ToString();
        }

        string text = (string)json;

        SkyWeather w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<SkyWeather>(text);

        return w.temp;
    }
}
```

How can I read it?

Comment: Well you've already got some code, I see - so what happens when you try to use it?

Comment: It returns '0' for me.

Comment: What is `SkyWeather` class definition?

Comment: So put that into your question. Now, I see that `temp` is only within the `main` property of your JSON... so how assuming the code you've shown is the `SkyWeather` class (which is unclear as you didn't provide the declaration) how would you expect that to have deserialized?

Comment: How is your SkyWeather class? main in SkyWeather should be defind as a class (contains property temp)

Comment: Yeah you'll need to provide the SkyWeather definition. Also, you are casting a string (json) to a string (text). No need to do that.

Comment: Why w.temp? why not w.main.temp ?

Comment: SkyWeather is my class, this is all the code that it contains.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Assuming that SkyWeather represents the properties in your "main" object, you'll need to create another object that represents the wrapping object:

```
public class RootObject
{
    public int id { get; set; }
    public int dt { get; set; }
    public string name { get; set; }
    public SkyWeather main { get; set; }
}
```

... and then:

```
    RootObject w = JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<RootObject>(text);

    return w.main.temp;
```

Comment: But "temp" doesn't exist inside main in RootObject.